# Progress bar in Windows activity field?

Tags: c++, progress-bar, progress

I've written a c++ program that performs time consuming calculations and i want the user to be able to see the progress while the program is running in the background (minimized).

I'd like to use the same effect as chrome uses when downloading a file:

[image: chrome progress]

How do i access this feature? Can i use it in my c++ program?

Comment: That's called a "taskbar progress indicator"; it was added to Windows 7 as a new feature, and is exposed by the `ITaskbarList3` interface.

Comment: A lot of [Taskbar extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378460.aspx) were added in Windows 7.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Perfect! I was probably using the wrong terms when searching for it.

Answer (score -1):

If the time consuming operation can be performed inside a loop, and depending on whether or not it is a count controlled loop, you may be able to use `thread` and `atomic` to solve your problem.
If your processor architecture supports multithreading you can use threads to run calculations concurrently. The basic use of a thread is to run a function in parallel with the main thread, these operations may be effectively done at the same time, meaning you would be able to use the main thread to check the progress of your time consuming calculations. With parallel threads comes the problem of data races, wherein if two threads try to access or edit the same data, they could do so incorrectly and corrupt the memory. This can be solved with `atomic`. You could use an `atomic_int` to make sure two actions are never cause a data race.

A viable example:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

//function prototypes
void foo(std::mutex * mtx, std::atomic_int * i);

//main function
int main() {
    //first define your variables
    std::thread bar;
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::atomic_int value;
    //store initial value just in case
    value.store(0);


    //create the thread and assign it a task by passing a function and any parameters of the function as parameters of thread
    std::thread functionalThread;
    functionalThread = std::thread(foo/*function name*/, &mtx, &value/*parameters of the function*/);

    //a loop to keep checking value to see if it has reached its final value

    //temp variable to hold value so that operations can be performed on it while the main thread does other things
    int temp = value.load();

    //double to hold percent value
    double percent;
    while (temp < 1000000000) {
        //calculate percent value
        percent = 100.0 * double(temp) / 1000000000.0;

        //display percent value
        std::cout << "The current percent is: " << percent << "%" << std::endl;

        //get new value for temp
        temp = value.load();
    }
    //display message when calculations complete
    std::cout << "Task is done." << std::endl;

    //when you join a thread you are essentially waiting for the thread to finish before the calling thread continues
    functionalThread.join();

    //cin to hold program from completing to view results
    int wait;
    std::cin >> wait;

    //end program
    return 0;
}

void foo(std::mutex * mtx, std::atomic_int * i) {
    //function counts to 1,000,000,000 as fast as it can
    for (i->store(0); i->load() < 1000000000; i->store(i->load() + 1)) {
        //keep i counting
        //the first part is the initial value, store() sets the value of the atomic int
        //the second part is the exit condition, load() returns the currently stored value of the atomic
        //the third part is the increment
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm curious what relevance you think this answer has to the question?

Comment: After rereading the question it seems I misunderstood the question